# How to Create textboxes dynamically based on rows in table of a database in asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I want to generate same numbers of Labels and TextBoxes depending on the numbers of my sql database's table rows. 
It will generate the same numbers of Labels and TextBoxes and retrieve 1 column data to the labels[The image shows a sample of database table and a webform design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbshe.png)

Comment: web forms or mvc ? your tag says MVC and question title says web forms.

Comment: sorry :( it is web form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Repeater or ListView control to create labels and text boxes dynamically:

.aspx:

```
<table>
    <asp:ListView id="lvSample" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("ItemID") %></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</table>
```

Then set the DataSource value from your code-behind. You can also set it from the .aspx using the DataSource control.

Comment: Thanks abramlimpin

Comment: Would you tell me, how I call the list view from aspx.cs?

Answer (score 0):

see this :

```
<% var data=(from e in table select e).ToList<type>(); %>
<% foreach(type dr in data)
{ %>
  <label><%=dr.Name %> </label>
  <input type="text" name="<%=dr.ItemID %>" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: I think the question is for WebForms not MVC.